Magento 2 WYSIWYG editor missing the bullet points icon
I am using Magento 2.4.2 for my current website. I am using the WYSIWYG editor in magento admin to edit product descriptions.
WYSIWYG editor is showing fine but is missing the bullet points icon. How can I show bullet points?

I already tried with this extension - https://github.com/magefan/module-wysiwyg-advanced but no luck.
Thank you.

Can add the full screenshot of the editor once - https://prnt.sc/e3gEAWkDlzB5
